# alternative proof : Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb R^d$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field making all continuous functions measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

This question is related to [Prove that Borel sigma field on R(d) is the smallest sigma-field that makes all continuous functions f:R(d)->R measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189567/235690)  I'm trying to prove this exercise in Durrett's book myself, and wonder if the following elementary arguments are valid:

First of all, for every continuous $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(E)$ is open, for any open set $E\in \mathbb R$.  So clearly the Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal B^d$ makes all continuous function measurable.

To show the $\mathcal B^d$ is the smallest such $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$, let $d=2$ for simplicity of arguments.  Consider two continuous functions: $g(x,y)=x$ and $h(x,y)=y$.  Note that $g^{-1}((a_1, b_1))=(a_1, b_1)\times(-\infty, \infty)$, and $h^{-1}((a_2, b_2))=(-\infty, \infty)\times(a_2, b_2)$.  So $\mathcal F$ must contain $\{(a_1, b_1)\times(-\infty, \infty):a_1, b_1\in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{(-\infty, \infty)\times(a_2, b_2):a_2, b_2\in \mathbb R\}$, and hence $\{(a_1, b_1)\times(a_2, b_2):a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2\in \mathbb R\}$.  This implies $\mathcal F\supset \mathcal B^2$ and hence $\mathcal F = \mathcal B^2$.  Extension to $d>2$ or $d=1$ is obvious.

Is this proof correct?  If there're flaws, I'd appreciate it if someone can point them out.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You miss the case $d=1$.

Comment: @md2perpe You're right.  It's fixed.  Thank you!